# Appcelerator - ERROR Could not find all required Titanium Modules

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules, appcelerator-titanium

Getting started with cloning a new Appcelerator project. I keep receiving this error. Many Appcelerator Google results are now archived and have not been able to access those Q/A.

I run the project via a Makefile that has:

```
all:
    @${MAKE} clean
    @${MAKE} compile
    @${MAKE} run-sim
init:
    ...
    @gittio install ti.airprint
    @gittio install bencoding.blur
    @gittio install de.marcelpociot.circularprogress
    @${MAKE} all
```

After running make init. A long compilation process happens followed by the following

```
  /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin/node /Users/username/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/bin/titanium build --platform ios --plugin-paths /Users/username/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules --config-file /var/folders/lj/c7hfzz254cd3lt2nxscv_wgw0000gn/T/build-1453310098056.json --log-level info --no-banner

[INFO]  Found Titanium module id=bencoding.blur version=0.37 platform=iphone deploy-type=development path=/Users/username/Jester/cruisers-dealers/modules/iphone/bencoding.blur/0.37
[INFO]  Found Titanium module id=de.marcelpociot.circularprogress version=1.1 platform=iphone deploy-type=development path=/Users/username/Jester/cruisers-dealers/modules/iphone/de.marcelpociot.circularprogress/1.1
[INFO]  Found Titanium module id=ti.worker version=1.1.0 platform=iphone deploy-type=development path=/Users/username/Jester/cruisers-dealers/modules/iphone/ti.worker/1.1.0
[WARN]  Could not find a valid Titanium module id=ti.airprint version=1.3.4 platform=iphone deploy-type=development
[INFO]  Found Titanium module id=ti.cloud version=3.2.9 platform=commonjs deploy-type=development path=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/commonjs/ti.cloud/3.2.9
[ERROR] Could not find all required Titanium Modules:
[ERROR]    id: ti.airprint   version: 1.3.4  platform: iphone    deploy-type: development

2016-01-20T17:15:02.058Z | ERROR  | ti run exited with error code 1
make[2]: *** [run-sim] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [init] Error 2
```

Update:

```
<modules>
    <module platform="iphone" version="0.37">bencoding.blur</module>
    <module platform="iphone" version="1.1">de.marcelpociot.circularprogress</module>
    <module version="1.1.0" platform="iphone">ti.worker</module>
    <module version="1.3.4" platform="iphone">ti.airprint</module>
    <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
</modules>
```

Update 2: After changing version on tiapp.xml to match that of the directory.

```
[Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 14, got 46.]
[ERROR] socket hang up
2016-01-20T18:16:24.368Z | ERROR  | ti run exited with error code 100
make[2]: *** [run-sim] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [init] Error 2
```

Comment: make sure it's in your modules directory

Comment: @developer82 what do you mean?

Comment: It is in the modules directory

Comment: what do you have in your tiapp.xml in the modules sections? can you paste how it's defined in there?

Comment: @developer82 I updated the question with that.

Comment: is 1.3.4 the version you have inside the modules directory?

Comment: @developer82 hmm, this what i have `projectname/modules/iphone/ti.airprint/1.4.3`

Comment: @developer82 updated question

Comment: try to remove the version number

Comment: @developer82 I think it may be another issue. Did that too and now get an invalid session error.

Comment: @developer82 had to `appc new --import --project-dir ./` to get it up and running.

Comment: everything is working now? If so, you can close this problem, adding the answer =)
If not... let me know so I can help you. Thanks

Comment: @DouglasHennrich yes it is running

Comment: @developer82 if you like, post an answer. i had to change the version number on tiapp to match the dir version.

Comment: @Beast_Code - I think you should post an answer to your question and mark it as best answer, and write exactly what you did, so others in the future who face the same issue could find the answer quickly. glad everything worked out.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the version number in `tiapp.xml`

```
<module version="1.3.4" platform="iphone">ti.airprint</module>
```

to match the `projectname/modules/iphone/ti.airprint/1.4.3` did it for me. So this

```
<module version="1.3.4" platform="iphone">ti.airprint</module>
```

did it. I received other errors after doing this, but that is beyond this question.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote 1.3.4 instead of 1.4.3, which is the correct version number.

1.3.4 is not existing in the releases: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.airprint/releases

Answer (score 0):

The last error you see (`[Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 14, got 46.]`) happens when you've changed your NodeJS version. An Node (NPM) Module that uses native extensions will need to be rebuild if the NodeJS version has a different API then the previous. If you use `ti` then re-install that via NPM. If you use `appc` then do `appc install 5.1.0 --force`.

Appcelerator is working on detecting this and rebuilding for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had compiled the module with a newer SDK than the one I was using in the project where I imported it. Appcelerator Studio pointed that out.